# Duplicate DataGridView by Button Click Event

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

does someone can help me out. I'm facing a Problem. I have a DataGridView on a C# Windows Form with a Button below. I want to copy exactly the same Column definitions on a new Table below when clicking the Button so a new DataGridView gets added with the same Column definition as the table above, so to say a exact copy of the DataGridView without Data inside.

Is there a way to achieve this. I didn't found anything on the internet that helped me.

Probably someone has an Idea?

Comment: Does your DGV have a DataSource? Is the Columns structure decided at run-time (setting the `DataSource`) or design-time (setting the `DataPropertyName` of each pre-built Column)?

Comment: Its always the same Grid with the same specs. It has 6 Columns first three are ComboBox Columns and the 4th is a TextBoxColumn and the last two are ButtonColumns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> private void Duplicate() 
>  {  DataGridView dataGridView2=new DataGridView();   
>       foreach(DataGridViewColumn col in datagridview1.Columns)   {
>  int index=datagridview1.Columns.indexOf(col);
>  dataGridView2.Columns[index].Name = col.Name;   }       
>  dataGridView2.Location=new
> Point(dataGridView1.Location.X,button.Location.Y+20);  
> this.Controls.Add(dataGridView2); 
>  }
> ```